# How to browse the internet with the home IP while traveling. (connect to the home network and use home IP)

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, vpn, dns

I am using my laptop (windows 10) to login to a website that is checking my (public) IP. Every time my IP changes or when I am traveling or I am away form home, I have to do a time consuming process of validating my new IP.

I need a way to connect to my home network with the same laptop and have the public IP from home.

I searched for this online and they were mostly info on connecting to your router page remotely or connecting to your home network for file sharing purposes. Doesn't really help if I make my laptop a vpn server because I need to connect to the home router IP using the same laptop. And I am not sure if or how a dynamic DNS would help here.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: You need a VPN from home. And here's the problem: It's not easy to setup and if you're asking such a question then it will be probably over your head.

Comment: I can handle technical stuff. I just needed to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @DennisKampien setting up a VPN is not at all difficult, however I would not bother with it.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question I'm assuming that you've only one laptop in possession and you want to use it to connect your home IP while away from home.

If that is the case, most of the other internet suggestions don't work for you. To use your home IP while away from your home, you've two options at best.

- Buy dedicated Firewall/VPN device and install/configure in your home so that you can connect to your home IP anywhere around the globe through VPN(which will cost you quite a bit of money).
- Configure VPN in your existing router if it is supported and if it is not, then you can install custom firmware like [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) or [dd-wrt](https://dd-wrt.com/) whichever have supporting custom firmware for your home router and configure VPN in your router(Though beware that installing third-party custom firmware in your router/AP will terminate any warranty that you have).
- And if you have any old desktop or laptop in your home you can set it up as VPN server by using [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) or [Softether](https://www.softether.org/)(I recommend Softether).
  (Yeah I said two but doesn't harm to add one more option if available.) This one might be the easiest option for you.

Though my answer doesn't give you step by step guide I hope it gives you general direction/idea to move. Installation/configuration instructions for above-mentioned firmware and VPN servers are available all over the internet and if you get stuck in any step you always have [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) to ask for help.

Comment: Also, once set up with any of the above options you can completely forget about it and keep on using it for a long time.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* VPN to your home network.  You could buy VPN hardware to do this, but that is an unnecessary investment.  You can install and configure free VPN server software, such as [OpenVPN](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Easy_Windows_Guide).  You dont even need to install software to create a VPN.  Here is a [guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/) that shows how to set up a VPN within Windows 10.

However, I would skip all that, and just use [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.us/).  TeamViewer will allow you to connect and use your home computer from anywhere.  When using TeamViewer, you are actually using your home computer and see its desktop as if you were sitting at it.  You can access it from your laptop on the go.  You dont even need your laptop, as you can access your home computer from the TeamViewer website.